# Join two tables with same # of row but sorted for NULL

Tags: sql, join, row-number

I need to join two tables with the same number of rows. Each table has 1 column. There is NO CONNECTING COLUMN to reference for a join. I need to join them side by side because each table was sorted separately so that numeric values are at the top in descinding order.

The Table Earners has income values from say 200K down to 0. I cannot just select using 2 cases, because then I will have my first row with Incomes above 100K, but the first 20 or so entries in the second row are NULL. I want the second row to also be sorted descending.

I looked up using ORDER BY within CASE but there is no such thing. I have tried to read about row_number() but none of the examples seem to match or make sense.

```
drop table #20plus
select
    case
        when Income >= 20000 AND Income < 100000
        then Income end as 'mula'
into #20plus
from Earners
order by mula desc


drop table #100plus
select
    case
        when Income >= 100000
        then Income end as 'dinero'
into #100plus
from Earners
order by dinero desc

Select A.dinero, B.mula
FROM #100plus as A JOIN #20plus as B
ON A.????? = B.?????
```

Since both A and B are sorted descending, moving all NULL to the bottom, what can I reference to join the two tables?

Previous output using one SELECT statement with 2 CASE statements

```
dinero             mula
2.12688e+007       NULL
1.80031e+007       NULL
1.92415e+006       NULL
…                  …
NULL               93530.7
NULL               91000
NULL               84500
```

Desired output using one SELECT statement after creating two temp TABLES

```
dinero          mula
2.12688e+007    93530.7
1.80031e+007    91000
1.92415e+006    84500
…               82500
NULL            82000
NULL            …
NULL            NULL
```

This is Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I'm super new to this, so please give an answer as clear and simplified as possible. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to add metadata of some sort, but I don't know exactly how to go about it. Relational databases aren't really built for this problem: you may want to add a second columns to each table with an 'ordering number', then join on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.dinero, B.mula
FROM #100plus as A FULL OUTER JOIN #20plus as B
ON A.dinero = B.mula
ORDER BY A.dinero,B.mula;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you divide your table into two and use row_number() to generate numbers by descending order, you can connect them by row_number. Note how numbers are produced - row_number is given order by.

```
; WITH _20plus AS (
     SELECT CASE WHEN income >= 20000 AND income < 100000 
                 THEN income 
             END AS Mula,
             Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN income >= 20000 AND income
                < 100000 THEN income END DESC) rn
       FROM earners
     ),
     _100plus AS (
     SELECT CASE WHEN income >= 100000 THEN income 
             END AS Dinero,
            Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN income >= 100000 
                                             THEN income END DESC) rn
       FROM earners
)
SELECT a.dinero,
       b.mula
FROM _100plus AS a
   INNER JOIN _20plus AS b
      ON a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: I have no idea how to use WITH yet (same as SELECT-INTO ?), but I think I can see what's happening here. I'll try it out using the temp tables. Thanks.

Comment: @VISQL [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is partly as any derived table, but is declared in more readable fashion. You could read more on CTE in a link I posted. If you do not want to use it, use derived table syntax instead of temporary tables. It is worth the trouble.